# How to remove all zero columns in MS Excel 2016 while keeping columns that have a some zero values?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a 10 rows X 50000+ columns. The problem is that there are some columns having ALL Zero values.
I need to remove only those columns while keeping the ones that have a few zero cells. 
an example is shown below

[image]

So it would become like this:

[image]

Comment: You will need VBA macro for this as excel formula cannot delete cells!

Comment: What you will need is a VBA loop that will go over all your columns and test if the sum of the entire column is over 1. Then delete all columns that are found.

Comment: any luck on the tries ?

Answer (score 2):

Select all > copy > (new excel sheet/file) r-click in A1 > (paste special) transpose

In the K1 cell put :

```
=if(sum(A1:J1)=0,1,"")
```

and drag the formula downwards.

Then highlight cell A1:K1 > Data > filter
Filter column K > select "1"

Then select all row (by selecting rows at left side) > r-click (at left side) > delete rows.

Remove filter, delete column K , select all > copy  (another new excel sheet/file) r-click in A1 > (paste special) transpose.

done.

Hope it helps.